# How to call solr API with Terms Query Parser

Tags: solr

I am calling the solr API and I want to use Terms Query Parser I have added syntax in filter query but it is not giving any results. Also the query parser is selected wrong when I check with debug.

```
......./solr/mail/select?_=1569934027956&debugQuery=on&fq={!terms+f=mailid+method=booleanQuery+separator="+"}3028+346&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json
```

Comment: As, I can see your "q" attribute only contains colon which will not give you much results, most probably it will return nothing. Try to append q=*:* or q=* with query to fetch all the results.

Comment: `+` needs to be explicitly escaped in URLs, since it's used to represented a space (as you can see between `{!terms` and `f` in your example. Use a different separator, such as the default `,` to test it properly.

Comment: @MatsLindh it wont matter because it will be interpreted as a " " anyway

Comment: can you show us some response from the server?